# How to solve the 'no such file' error in docker?

Tags: docker

I am new to docker. When I am trying to run the following code in Docker (powershell),

```
docker run -v 'pwd':/work name/exercise
```

I am getting the following error

```
/bin/sh: 1: cannot open /work/my-saying.txt: No such file.
```

But the file exists

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, can you specify some more details ? How does your dockerfile look like ? you are creating a new volume with `-v` flag. Have you placed the file inside that volume ?

Comment: Thank you. The edited question has the complete code

Comment: Ok, It would be easier to understand the problem if you could show your dockerfile as well.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to many issues since it's not very clear:

1. check that you're sharing your drives
2. check if there's any permission restriction on that file
3. docker run -v /work:name/exercise4 , there's a missing : in your
   command